# How do I send a POST request based on text field change? (without the use of a submit button)

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I want to have an app where a user types into a text field. After the user is done, the form automatically "submits" a POST request. (There should be a delay of say, 2 seconds after the user stops typing).

I don't know how to do this--I imagine it requires some javascript or more machinery. I'm working in flask/Python.

I've extensively searched through SO for these solutions but can't find somewhere to get started.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a button? It sounds like you're new to javascript, and it's probably a better learning step to get the post request working with a button, and as a later enhancement, you could figure out how to monitor user typing. Is your backend in flask/Python?

Comment: What you are talking about can be done, but how would you know for sure that the user is completely satisfied with what they have typed? If you dont care then I can post an answer

Comment: @ann-kilzer I have a working solution that uses a submit button. It's just copy and paste from a tutorial, and not directly relevant to the question, so I didn't post it.

Comment: @sasy-solutions fair enough. I have some design ideas that motivate my question. It's like a spell check, where the user expects and wants feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Execute a JavaScript when a user changes the content of an input field:

```
<input type="text" onchange="sendData()" id="myData">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

and then you can POST with xmlhttprequest
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp

```
      var stuff = document.getElementById("myData").value;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      var p ='https://example.com/whereyouwantyourposttogo';
      xhr.open('POST', p, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //do your stuff when the POST data comes back
      };
//if you want to send JSON data do JSON.stringify(stuff) inside the send
//for example xhr.send(JSON.stringify(stuff));
      xhr.send(stuff);
```